# The 5 Reindeer - Permutations & combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

You need to put your reindeer, Gloopin, Balthazar, Bloopin, Prancer, and Quentin, in a single-file line to pull your sleigh. **However, Prancer and Balthazar are best friends, so you have to put them next to each other, or they won't fly.**

**How many ways can you arrange your reindeer?**

---

I know there is another question asking the same thing, but my question is not what that person was asking. Mine is different.

I know and understand this:

---

1. So, the total number of unique choices we could make to get to an
   arrangement of reindeer is $5⋅4⋅3⋅2⋅1 = 120$. Another way of writing
   this is 5! or 5 factorial. But we haven't thought about the two
   reindeer who have to be together yet.
2. We can count the number of arrangements where Prancer and Balthazar
   are together by treating them as one double-reindeer. Now we can use
   the same idea as before to come up with $4⋅3⋅2⋅1 = 24$ different
   arrangements. But that's not quite right.
3. Why? Because you can arrange the double-reindeer with Prancer in
   front or with Balthazar in front, and those are different
   arrangements! **So the actual number of arrangements with Prancer and
   Balthazar together is $24⋅2 = 48$**

---

I do not understand why you have to multiply 24 by 2 to get the answer. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: You gave the explanation yourself under point $3$.  Every arrangement with the double reindeer actually represents two different arrangements with single reindeer.  What is it you don't follow about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you consider the reindeer next to each other you get $4!$, but this has not been generalized, because the order Prancer and Balthazar can be switched to Bathazar and Prancer, and still satisfy the requirement of them being next to eachother.

For instance, let Prancer, Balthazar, Bloopin, Gloopin, and Quentin be one combination of the $4!$ combinations. But Balthazar, Prancer, Bloopin, Gloopin, and Quentin are also a valid combination but you only counted one of these two combinations.

Comment: Tell me if I understand this correctly: You have one combination which is Prancer, Balthazar, Bloopin, Gloopin, and Quentin out of 24. You can mix the other reindeers which are the other 23 combinations without unpairing Prancer, Balthazar. In addition, you can have Balthazar, Prancer, Bloopin, Gloopin, and Quentin which is another one combination out of 24, and you can mix the other reindeers which are the other 23 combinations without unpairing Prancer, Balthazar.

Comment: Thus, having 2 sets of combinations where the other reindeers (not Prancer, Balthazar) can be mixed without unpairing them. Hence you multiply by 2 to get the answer.

Comment: Pretty much. The key is to think of them as one object that can be written 2 different ways, as saulspatz said above. As one object, written one way(let's say Prancer first, then Balthazar), there are 4! combinations. Then reversing their order but keeping them as one object(so Balthazar first, Prancer second), you get another 4! combinations, thus 2*4!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!